# EJS syntax error, not able to compile the file?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, web-development-server

I am encountering a SyntaxError while trying to compile an EJS template. The template is used to display a table with months and corresponding data. However, I receive the following error message:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' in D:\code while compiling ejs

```
<tbody>

                        <% for(let i=0;i<12;i++){ %>

                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"> <%= i+1 %></th>
                                <% switch(i) { %>
                                    <% case 0 : %>
                                        <td>January</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                    <% case 1 : %>
                                        <td>February</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                    <% case 2 : %>
                                        <td>March</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                    <% case 3 : %>
                                        <td>April</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                    <% case 4 : %>
                                        <td>May</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                    <% case 5 : %>
                                        <td>June</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                    <% case 6 : %>
                                        <td>July</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                    <% case 7 : %>
                                        <td>August</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                    <% case 8 : %>
                                        <td>September</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                    <% case 9 : %>
                                        <td>October</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                    <% case 10 : %>
                                        <td>November</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                    <% case 11 : %>
                                        <td>December</td>
                                        <% break; %>
                                <% } %>
                                
                                <td><%= perMonthAttendance[i] %></td>
                                <td><%= perMonthCharges[i] %></td>
                                <td><%= perMonthStatus[i] %></td>
                            </tr>
                        <% } %>
                       
                    </tbody>
```

I was expecting that the code will run without any syntax error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62816031/19224040